# MFC Tri-state CheckBox — how to change the order of the states?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, checkbox, mfc

How to change the order of tri-state MFC CheckBox control?

Now when I click it has the followins states order:
BST_INDETERMINATE > BST_UNCHECKED > BST_CHECKED > cycle

But I need the following:
BST_INDETERMINATE > BST_CHECKED > BST_UNCHECKED > cycle

Comment: Have you tried providing a handler for the click message and changing the state from whatever it was/is to whatever you want it to be?

Comment: Yes, I tried OnClick — no success.

Comment: How is your checkbox defined (in the resource script)? Is it an `AUTOCHECKBOX`? If so, maybe make it non-AUTO (just `CHECKBOX`) and handle setting the states yourself.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It was BS_AUTO3STATE. I've changed it to BS_3STATE and it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Adrian Mole for the comment tip!

I forgot to change from BS_AUTO3STATE to BS_3STATE.

The working solution:

```
void CTestDialog::OnCheckBoxClicked() 
{   
    int state = ((CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECKBOX))->GetCheck();
    if (state == BST_INDETERMINATE)
        ((CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECKBOX))->SetCheck(BST_CHECKED);
    else if (state == BST_CHECKED)
        ((CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECKBOX))->SetCheck(BST_UNCHECKED);
    else
        ((CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECKBOX))->SetCheck(BST_INDETERMINATE);
}
```